issue when installing pdfminer.six in python 3.2.12 on windows 10
I want to install pdfminer.six to extract text from pdf files.
I cannot do it with python 3.12.2
This is the output of the command pip install pdfminer.six
PS C:\Users\Admin\resume_ai> pip install pdfminer.six
Requirement already satisfied: pdfminer.six in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (20231228)
Requirement already satisfied: charset-normalizer>=2.0.0 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from pdfminer.six) (3.3.2)
Requirement already satisfied: cryptography>=36.0.0 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from pdfminer.six) (42.0.5)
Requirement already satisfied: cffi>=1.12 in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from cryptography>=36.0.0->pdfminer.six) (1.16.0)
Requirement already satisfied: pycparser in c:\users\admin\appdata\local\programs\python\python312\lib\site-packages (from cffi>=1.12->cryptography>=36.0.0->pdfminer.six) (2.22)


without completing the installation
Have you any solution to this issue?
Thank you

The solution is doing python -m pip install pdfminer.six instead of directly doing pip install pdfminer.six.
